# VTK/Java Wrapper in IntelliJ won't work because of linker errors (Can't find dependent libraries)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, linker, wrapper, vtk

Im running Java 1.8.0_065 (64 Bit) on Windows 10 (64 bit). I've downloaded the latest cmake version (3.4.0-rc2) for windows and the latest VTK sources (6.3.0). I generated a VS2015 solution via cmake and set up everything (seemingly!!) successfully using this tutorial:

https://www.particleincell.com/2011/vtk-java-visualization/

When I try to run the DemoJavaVTK.java which is provided by the tutorial I get linker errors in IntelliJ. (14.1.5) At apperently every VTK library that has to be loaded there is the same error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\VTK\bin\ANY_VTK_DLL.dll: Can't find dependent libraries  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)  at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)    at
>   vtk.vtkNativeLibrary.LoadLibrary(vtkNativeLibrary.java:223)   at
>   vtk.vtkNativeLibrary.LoadAllNativeLibraries(vtkNativeLibrary.java:158)
>     at sample.DemoJavaVTK.(DemoJavaVTK.java:54)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)

*Mind that ANY_VTK_DLL is just a placeholder. Concrete examples would be: vtkViewsContext2DJava.dll or vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGLJava.dll.*

The path should be correct. All the "versions" are 64 bit. I compiled VTK for 64 Bit. I'm running a 64 bit OS with 64 bit java.

The wierdest thing is: Using eclipse everything works fine and I can run the VTK-demo without any problems. Also I'm using VTK for a course at my university, I'm working on my project with a colleague who has the same java and intellij version. He also used the same tutorial to set up VTK/Java. And the example also works in IntelliJ for him. The only difference I can tell between his and my system is, that he is using Windows 8.1 and I am using windows 10.

I really don't know where to continue from here. What is IntelliJs problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it fixed out of pure randomness by manually setting the JRE via the Run-configurations:

http://puu.sh/l3315/7c1d5e3393.png

Why does this work?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

*The **UnsatisfiedLinkError** denotes that the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared as **native**.    Specifically, in order to find the required native library, the JVM looks in both the PATH environment variable and the java.library.path system property.* (Got from [this article](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-how-to-handle-unsatisfied-link-error/))

I used to have this kind of problems mostly because two causes:

1. The native librarie cannot be found (i.e don't exist)
2. The library being linked is not the same (Debug vs Release, 32 bit
   vs 64 bit, VC10 vs VC9, etc.)
3. The library is already loaded by your application and the application tries to load it again
4. The native library is present either in the java.library.path or in the PATH environment library of your application

In order to be sure to whom library you are linking use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Using this tool will make you understand what's wrong by telling you to which native libraries you are linking to.

Download the tool and then open *C:\Program Files\VTK\bin\ANY_VTK_DLL.dll* to see to which library it's linking to and where they are in your machine. Then make sure that IntelliJ can find these paths.

Here is a good tuto on how to use this tool: http://www-archive.mozilla.org/quality/help/dependency-walker.html

If they are the correct ones, verify the class path that IntelliJ Idea uses to launch your application to check that the native libraries are there.

Comment: These paths: http://puu.sh/l26r0/b5fad53e57.png ??
Well then there really shouldn't be a problem. C:\Program Files\VTK\bin is in path (Else he wouldn't even be able to locate the dlls in the first place) and C:\Windows\system32 is in path per default.

Also: If my system path variable would be missing some stuff for VTK, it wouldn't be working using eclipse, right?

Answer (score 0):

I could run using,
System.setProperty("vtk.lib.dir", YourBuildVTKLibPath);

Answer (score -1):

I am new using VTK, took me a while to fix this, I am using eclipse ,

I added to the PATH environment variable the dll folder and the lib folder

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an actual answer or just a "Me too!" response.  If it's the former, please remove the bits that are not useful to the questioner.  If it's the latter, please remove it entirely.